# How many sobol sequences should I generate for sensitivity analysis?

Tags: sensitivity-analysis

I have a benchmark application that has 10 variables of different ranges.

The application has one output a value measuring the performance of the application.

I want to determine which of the parameters effect the output so I generate c * (n+2) sequences where n = 10 (params), c = 250 (arbitrary) using SALib library.

Is there a rule of thumb that determines lowest value of c that I can use? at 250 the run time becomes too large.

Comment: I guess increasing `c` will reduce std..?

Comment: When you say sequences, do you mean evaluations of your model? If it is the case this is clearly not enough. Reading some papers you'll usually see more than 100 000 function evaluations (up to a million). When the run time is too large, the usual go to is to use a surrogate model.